# Mouse pointer avoids RDP bar during screen sharing and moves irratically

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, mouse, microsoft-teams

I have a desktop Windows 10 computer (with two screens) and two laptops with Windows 10.

During my day-to-day work I use remote desktop from my desktop to either laptop. That normally works perfectly fine and without lagging or other issues.

Both computers have Ms Teams and sometimes I also screen share on them.
On one of them, everything works as expected in all instances.

On the other, when using remote desktop and screen share with ms teams, the mouse is "jumpy" and it sort of avoids the blue "rdp bar" at the top - as soon as it gets on top of the bar, the mouse pointer jumps off. I can still use the rdp bar, but I have to make several attempts.

As soon as I quit the screen sharing, the behavior stops. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

By coincidence - the problem disappeared after an update done just a few hours later. I keep my computer up to date so somehow I just happened to get this specific fix the same day I decided to post the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I RDP into a box at work. Sharing either of my monitors causes the mouse pointer to be so jumpy I can barely use it. I keep all my PCs fully updated (Win 10) so I know this is not an update thing.

Still seeking the answer.